# HTML class = Ajax action, how to get the class clicked to call the good action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

## Context

I have 3 buttons on several lines (edit, delete, unsuscribe).

This 3 buttons are 3 different classes but the same click handler.

**This classes are equals to the names of 3 actions using for an ajax call.**

So into the click handler, I need to retrieve the specific part of the selector which has been clicked.

Currently I use the following code that I wrote

## Question

**In 2-3 lines and using class=action system**, is there a better way to solve my issue?

I'm looking for something like that but I didn't find:

```
$.post(url + '&action=' + classClickedIntoTheSelector.replace(/\./g, '') ...
```

---

## Code + [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wj3R/1/)

```html
<button class="actionLink edit btn">Éditer</button>
<button class="actionLink delete btn btn-warning">Supprimer</button>​
```

```javascript
$('.edit, .delete').click(function () {
    var a = $('.this, .that').selector.replace(/\./g, '').split(', ');
    var b = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var action;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            action = a[i] == b[j] ? a[i] : action;
        }            
    }
    
    $.post(url + '&action=' + action...
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the generic class and a data-attribute:

```html
<button class="actionLink btn" data-action="edit">Éditer</button>
<button class="actionLink btn" data-action="delete">Supprimer</button>​
```

```javascript
$j('.actionLink').click(function () {
    $.post(url + '&action=' + $(this).data('action'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var l = function (x) { return console.log(x); };

$('.this, .that').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);        
    if ($this.hasClass("this")) {
        l("this");
    }
    if ($this.hasClass("that")) {
        l("that");
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3wj3R/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).is('.this')) ...
if($(this).is('.that')) ...
```